# Highlighting links from websites with a browser extension

Tags: javascript, browser, hyperlink, highlight

I'm looking to develop a browser extension that would recognize links from news websites and display that articles' content in a popup screen upon a mouseover. The problem is, I have no idea where to start. I have past experience in HTML, CSS, and Javascript but in terms of browser extensions I'm a fish out of water. Could someone explain to me how one would go about starting something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create new extensions for Chrome [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fgetstarted&ei=BHT1U_ikH8a_uATEvIKwAw&usg=AFQjCNHcq8i50SHCgJq6o5GXP-VhGcyqSQ&sig2=k-k5B_Sb2giHqHQuRtZ1Qg&bvm=bv.73231344,d.c2E) may be useful to you...
[or refer this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fdeveloperworks%2Fweb%2Flibrary%2Fos-extendchrome%2Findex.html&ei=BHT1U_ikH8a_uATEvIKwAw&usg=AFQjCNFBqN8RExOQq3qn7IdYBVZIWxAHhw&sig2=5nzzcmUcrLNL4cgaHlGC1g&bvm=bv.73231344,d.c2E)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also an extension noob, but I know of a really good jQuery plugin for making the hover popups (tooltips).
  http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/tooltip/index.html